# Why does this work with Master Page Gallery but not Style Library

Tags: sandbox-solution

Please don't mock my code, I am just wondering why this does not work for Style Library but it works for the Master Page Gallery

```
                if (siteCollection != null)
            {
                SPList masterPageLibrary = rootWeb.Lists["Style Library"];
                if (masterPageLibrary != null)
                {

                    string featureId = properties.Feature.Definition.Id.ToString();

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(featureId))
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("featureId");
                    }
                    SPFileCollection files = masterPageLibrary.RootFolder.Files;
                    var checkedOutFiles = from SPFile f
                                          in files
                                          where String.Equals(f.Properties["FeatureId"] as string, featureId, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                                          select f;


                    foreach (SPFile f in checkedOutFiles)
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                f.CheckOut();
                                f.Update();
                            }
                            catch { }
                            //try to check in
                            try
                            {
                                f.CheckIn("Automatically checked in by feature activation", SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                                f.Update();
                            }
                            catch { }
                            //try to publish
                            try
                            {
                                f.Item.File.Publish("automatically published by feature activation");
                                f.Update();
                            }
                            catch { }


                            //try to approve
                            try
                            {
                                f.Item.File.Approve("Automatically approved by feature activation");
                                f.Update();

                            }
                            catch { }
                        }

                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Matthew Hughes

Comment: can you debug it?  Where is it failing and is what is the error message(if any)?

Comment: also, you should use rootWeb.Lists.TryGetList[listname]  instead of rootWeb.Lists[listname] as the former gives you a chance to avoid throwing an exception if the list is not found

Answer (score 1):

You're only looking for files in the RootFolder, which is where all the files are in the Master Page Gallery, but usually none of the files in Style Library

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should attempt using a piece from the example available on stackoverflow (the title you should use is "Master Page Gallery" to be sure)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716074/retrieve-all-master-pages-for-a-sharepoint-site

Looping through list items can be achieved in multiple ways:

1. Starting from the example code would need to adapt the CAML query to
   target specific items to reduce the items returned (e.g the example
   searches for .master pages) and reuse the piece of code looping
   through list items while checking for the File property is is not
   NULL(means that you have a file) or for the Folder property (means
   that you are accessing a folder).
2. If you know the exact path to your Folder start loading in there
   using something like  (see here for more folder operations examples http://avinashkt.blogspot.com/2010/03/spfolder-related-operations-in.html):

   parentWeb.GetFolder(folderName);
   if (folder != null) 
   { //start looping }

Comment: He is trying to get the code which works when using "Master Page Gallery" to work with "Style Library"